# How Do I remove the validation in jquery when either one of the fields are entered

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose i have two text fields t1 and t2 and when T1 is entered we need to remove 
validation for t2  and when T2 is entered we need to remove for T1

Iam using addClass()  and removeClass() methods

```
if($("input:text").val()!=''){
  $("#txt1").attr('class','validate[optional] ');
  $("#txt2").attr('class','validate[optional] ');
}
```

But My problem is when i enter in "txt2 "  still the "txt1" is asking for validation  and the reverse is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) will get the value of the *first* element in the set, that's why the reverse works.

Instead look if there are any non-empty ones, like this:

```
if($("input:text[value!='']").length) {
  $("#txt1, #txt2").attr('class','validate[optional]');
}
```

Comment: Nick:It says Object doesnot support this property or method

Comment: @Someone - which validation plugin are you using?

Comment: http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/